# C++ / Arduino: dynamic int array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, integer, arduino

I'm writing a class for the Arduino. It's been going well so far, but I'm sort of stuck now...

I have declared an int array in my class

```
class myClass
{
  public: MyClass(int size);
  private:
    int _intArray[];
};
```

When I initialize the class `MyClass myClass1(5)` I need the array to look like this {0,0,0,0,0}.

My question: what do I need to do so that the array contains 'size' amount of zeros?

```
MyClass::MyClass(int size)
{
    //what goes here to dynamically initialize the array
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++) _intArray[i] = 0;
}
```

Edit: Following up on various replies below, Arduino does not include the standard library so unfortunately `std::vector` is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as I'm writing this:

```
class myClass
{
  public: MyClass(int size);
  private:
    int _intArray[];
};
```

The declaration of `_intArray` is not valid C++: a raw array needs to have a size specified at compile time.

You can instead instead use a `std::vector`:

```
class myClass
{
public:
    MyClass( int size )
        : intArray_( size )    // Vector of given size with zero-valued elements.
    {}

private:
    std::vector<int> intArray_;
};
```

*Note 1*: some compilers may allow your original code as a language extension, in order to support the "struct hack" (that's a C technique that's not necessary in C++).

*Note 2*: I've changed the name of your member. Generally underscores at the start of names can be problematic because they may conflict with names from the C++ implementation.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I get an error saying "ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type" ledLib.h:40: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type
MyClass.h:40: error: invalid use of '::'
MyClass.h:40: error: expected ';' before '<' token
MyClass.h: In constructor 'MyClass::MyClass(int)':
MyClass.h:36: error: class 'MyClass' does not have any field named 'intArray_'

Comment: @JNK: have you included `<vector>` header?

Comment: I included it (now) but it doesn't change anything...:(

Comment: I found a work-around by simply passing an array to the class and using the pointer later on... not perfect but it works

Comment: @JNK: using a raw array has many problems for the novice. if you want to pursue that line then read up on the "rule of three". the simplest is to get the `std::vector` working -- it should not be a problem (it works for everyone else).

Comment: Arduino does not include the standard library that typically C++ is bundled with - `std::vector` is not available

Comment: @Brendan: I wasn't aware, but checking it, as of **some years ago** there were ways to get it. You may find this helpful: (http://andybrown.me.uk/2011/01/15/the-standard-template-library-stl-for-avr-with-c-streams/). Also see (https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus/blob/master/README.md), a standard library implementation for Arduino Of course, if Arduino tools now support  this themselves then no problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a std::vector.

```
class myCLass {
public:
    myClass(int size)
        : intarray(size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) intarray[i] = 0;
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> intarray;
};
```

Comment: why not ": intarray(size,0) {"  ?

Comment: @Oxsnarder: Meh, not really that versed in vector's constructors.

Comment: The zeroing loop is not ncessary: `std::vector` guarantees to zero those elements.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try the following:

```
class myClass
{
  public: 
    MyClass(int size);
    ~MyClass();
  private:
    int* _intArray;
};

MyClass::MyClass(int size) {
  _intArray = new int[size];
  for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) _intArray[i] =0; // or use memset ...
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {
  delete[] _intArray;
}
```

Or, even better, use a STL `vector` instead ...

Answer (score 2):

You should really use vectors as others have suggested. A work-around could be as shown (in case you do not want to use memcpy or a loop).

This would be useful if you have a really huge array. Note that it would add a level of indirection to access the array.

```
class myClass 
{ 
public: 
   myClass(){
      mt = T();    // value initialize.
   }
private:
   struct T{
      int _intArray[10]; 
   } mt;
};

int main(){
   myClass m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use another hack basing on a string value and then populate a limited size array
check this :
https://github.com/Riadam/ViewPort-Array-Shifter-for-Arduino-Uno.git

Comment: I think I've seen another of your posts... where you got asked to inline your code in case the linked resource rots.